# Enable Pegination on JQuery dialog in aspnet MVC using the PagedList

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a JQuery dialog window displaying table data. I have used the Paged List to enable paging where the records are more than 5. I want to be able  to navigate to a different page number on the dialog.

Here is my attempt so.

Action method :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetRequistionDetail(int RequestID, int? page)

        {
           // RequistionDetails myrequests = new RequistionDetails();
            List<RequistionDetails> listofdetails = new List<RequistionDetails>();           
            ViewBag.RequestID = RequestID;
            RequistionDetails myrequests = new RequistionDetails();           
            IPagedList<RequistionDetails> s = null;
            int pagesize = 5;
            int pagenumber = (page ?? 1);
            listofdetails = r.getAllRequistionsDetails(RequestID);
            myrequests.details = listofdetails;
            s = listofdetails.ToPagedList(pagenumber, pagesize);
            ViewBag.RequestID = RequestID;
            return PartialView("_details",s);


        }
```

In the index page, i use JQuery to open the dialog and load the data.
Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#dialogdiv").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 800,
                modal: true,
                maxHeight: window.innerHeight - 15,
                overflow: 'scroll',
                buttons: [{
                         text: "Ok",
                            click: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                            },
                    {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
            ]
            });
        $('.ids').click(function () {

            var requestid = $(this).data('id');
            //alert("You clicked me...again" + requestid)
            //var productId = $(this).data('id');
            //alert(requestid)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/tblRequistions/GetRequistionDetail",
                data: '{RequestID: "' + requestid + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#dialogdiv').html(response);
                    $('#dialogdiv').dialog('open');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

    });


</script>
```

In the index (main page), the dialog is represented by the div element.

```
<div id= "dialogdiv" title="View Requistion Details">
        </div>
```

The partial view which the dialog uses, has the following html and js code.

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model PagedList.IPagedList<LearningApp.ViewModel.RequistionDetails>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount


    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Requistion List</h4>
        <hr />
        <table class="table table-bordered  table table-hover" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" id="RequestGrid">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Name#</th>
                <th>Period</th>
                <th>Request Type</th>
                <th>Allowance Rate</th>
                <th>Days Requested</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Normal Days</th>
                <th>Field Days</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var r in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@r.Employee</td>
                    <td>@r.Period</td>
                    <td>@r.RequistionTypes</td>
                    <td>@r.AllowanceRate</td>
                    <td>@r.ndays</td>
                    <td>@r.Amount</td>
                    <td>@r.StartDate</td>
                    <td>@r.Enddate</td>
                    <td>@r.NormalDays</td>
                    <td>@r.FieldDays</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
          <div id="myPager">
            @Html.PagedListPager(Model,page => Url.Action("GetRequistionDetail",
            new
            {
                RequestID = ViewBag.RequestID, page = page
            }),PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions
            {
                Display=PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
                MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay=5

            },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod="Get",
                UpdateTargetId= "dialogdiv"


            }
        )
    )
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
<script>
    $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        //alert(this.href)
        //prevent action link normal functionality
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'Get',            
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result)
                $('#dialogdiv').html(result);

            },
            failure: function (result) {
                console.log(result)

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

When i click on the paging control, and i check in the console, i see the correct Url(`tblRequistions/GetRequistionDetail?RequestID=30&page=2`) returned but i get  Htpp status of 404 
not found.
So if i am getting the correct Url, why do i get not found status?
Anything i have implemented wrongly?
Ronald

Answer (score 0):

`data` in ajax call would be your issue. You have two parameters in `GetRequistionDetail` action, but you post just one of them (`RequestID`) in following line:

```
 data: '{RequestID: "' + requestid + '" }',
```

If `page` were added, it would have worked properly.

Comment: That one Ajax request you refer to is one in the main index page. Not the one for the PagedList.